# Does not appear to actually sync to one drive nor can I find a local copy

Tags: synchronization, onedrive, sharepoint-online

I got this message from my user:

"Working on a document sharepoint this morning, I was taking notes in one file and then went to open another. This caused Word to stop working and I had close word. When I reopened Word it offered me recovered files and the one that was available for the first document said it was an autosaved copy, so I did not resave it.

Well that version was not on one drive and when I reopened the file from the folder I had lost 45 minutes of work. This situation of information not syncing to one drive simply disappearing is not OK. Every time I save a document it takes two whole minutes to save but at my email yesterday said, it does not appear to actually sync to one drive nor can I find a local copy. "

Answer (score 0):

This is unclear - if she was working on a document in SharePoint and Word shut down, assuming version history is turned on in SharePoint, she should be able to return to SP and retrieve the latest version.  Autosave is defined at the local client level.  OneDrive is a different platform.  She could have been working on a Word document that lives in a SharePoint site/library synced to her local computer (and accessible via File Explorer) via the OneDrive for Business sync client.  If so, this has been known to happen occasionally - related to ODFB sync.  Enterprise wide it's worth checking to see if the sync client is the current version.  For your user, assuming versioning is on in SharePoint, ask her to go to SharePoint to retrieve the latest version of the document.  Also check global policy (if this is an Office Pro Plus scenario) for auto-save configs in Office files.  Good luck.